# Fargate: Can I restart specific containers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

**Containers**

- Bastion SSH servers for my private network.
- rsync server for providing authorized_keys to SSH servers.

  - The repository for rsync server commits include some new authorized_keys.

When pushing new commits to my rsync ECR, I want to restart containers excluding SSH servers.

Can I satisfy this in only one task? or, should I isolate a SSH job?

If there are any mentioned documents too, please share it.

Comment: I'm feeling I can't satisfy in only one task...

Answer (score 1):

If by restart you mean to replace, I don't think this is possible. If you change the docker image tag for a specific container inside the task definition, the task is changed and versioned as a whole. For this particular use case, It'd be a better idea to use different task definitions.

About [Amazon ECS Task Definitions]:(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definitions.html):

> Your entire application stack does not need to exist on a single task definition, and in most cases it should not. Your application can span multiple task definitions by combining related containers into their own task definitions,